# Laravel blade relationships using models

Tags: php, laravel

I have a relationship between these 3 models

```
class Teach extends Model {

public function departments() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Department', 'teach', 'id', 'department_id');
}

public function subjects() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject', 'teach', 'id', 'subject_id');
}

public function teachers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Teacher', 'teach', 'id', 'teacher_id');
} 
}
```

I want to list all departments and subjects of a specific teacher using these relation I've tried this in my view but it doesn't work
$teacher->teach->departments;

Comment: Well, this is your Teach model and not Teacher (and you wrote you want to display teacher in view), you didn't include your view and you didn't include error you got

Comment: Try this : `$teacher->teach()->departments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Many to Many relationship between teacher and departments

```
class Teacher extends Model {

  public function departments() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Department', 'teach', 'teacher_id', 'department_id');
  }

}


class Department extends Model {

  public function teachers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Teacher', 'teach', 'department_id', 'teacher_id');
  }

}
```

Now fetch  data

```
$teacher = Teacher::with('departments')->find(1);
$departments = $teacher->departments;
```